# Arduino method name clashes with library function

Tags: c++, arduino

I have this simple blink example, modified to declare a class whose only method signature matches that of the delay library function. It crashes the Arduino unless I rename the method. I see that the Arduino.h header has the "extern C" linkage specifier, so there should not be any name conflicts.
Could you help me understand this error?

Regards.

```
class Wrapper
{
public:
  void delay(unsigned long t)
  {
    delay (t); 
  }
};

Wrapper wr;

Wrapper* wrp = &wr;


// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  wrp->delay(1000);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  wrp->delay(1000);              // wait for a second
}
```

Comment: What do you meant when you say "crashes"? Do you get compilation error? Or is something happening during run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as listed has a stack overflow issue.  Within `Wrapper::delay(unsigned long)`, `delay(t)` calls `Wrapper::delay` again rather than the [Arduino `delay()` routine](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Delay).

If you want to call the Arduino `delay()` routine within `Wrapper::delay`, you need to qualify the call like so:

```
class Wrapper
{
public:
  void delay(unsigned long t)
  {
    ::delay(t);
  }
};
```